# Phonegap - page shows but doesn't load javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have these 2 html files (simplified to show the problem i'm having):

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
<meta name="viewport"
    content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="app.initialize();">

<a href="calendar.html">My Calendar</a>

</body>
</html>
```

calendar.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
<meta name="viewport"
    content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>


</head>
<body onload="app.initialize();">
<a href="index.html">Index</a>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var app = {

        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents()
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false)
        },

        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready')
        },

        receivedEvent: function(id){

            alert(location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))

        }

}
```

Now when the app first starts it alerts with the message "index.html".
But after that, everytime I click the links to bounce between the 2 pages, the content is shown (the respective links to the other page) but I get no alert, meaning the javascript is not beeing loaded again. But if I refresh the page the alert shows up. I want this to load the javascript without needing to refresh the page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the device is already ready by the time you've selected the next page and thus it won't fire the "deviceready" event again.

I'd change the structure of both pages to:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
<meta name="viewport"
    content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="calendar.html">My Calendar</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Note I've moved index.js underneath jQuery mobile and removed the "onload" event.

Then I'd take advantage of the pagecreate event from jQuery mobile to trigger the alert

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  app.initalize();
});

var app = {

        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
            $(document).on("pagecontainershow", app.onDeviceReady);
        },

        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready')
        },

        receivedEvent: function(id){

            alert($.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('getActivePage').data('url'));

        }

}
```

Comment: well now it alerts the "index.html" everytime i click 'My Calendar' when i was expecting it to alert "calendar.html", and when i click 'Index' it just goes back to index.html without any alerts. It never alerts "calendar.html"

Comment: I've changed the event to fire on show instead of change. Because of the way that jQuery Mobile loads pages, the "location" property won't work. Try the more jQuery-mobile specific way in the code above.

Comment: ok i fixed it now :) used "pageshow" event that triggers on the destination page. Thanks for the help